# height: auto on flex item when parent's height is 100vh

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to set flex child's height to auto when its **parent's position is fixed** and height is 100vh. the code as following below (class="firstInnerDiv" is my popup)

```
<style>
.maindiv{
    position:fixed;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background:#8c8c8c;
   }

.maindiv .firstInnerDiv{
    padding:0px 20px;
    margin-top:70px;
    border-radius:18px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    background:#fff;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="maindiv">
<div class="firstInnerDiv">
<p>1. More contents will be here </p>
</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle as follows

[link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjyrftxy/)

Comment: `height: 100vh` is problematic on mobiles as the `vh` changes when the user scrolls down and everything has to be recalculated again due to the change in the viewer height.

Comment: "firstInnerDiv" is my popup. how do I fill white background to my entire content? have you seen jsfiddle which I have attached. Anyhow thanks for the response

Comment: Your CSS already sets height to auto. What are you actually trying to accomplish, and what is the issue with the CSS you've got?

Comment: Please look at my "link to jsfiddle", where white background is not completely covering the content with parent div's position as fixed. this is my exact issue @Adrian

Comment: I realise this has been answered (and the answer helped me which is great) but is `position: fixed` actually relevant? I see it's in bold in the question, but when I run the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de5b7hc2/) the unwanted behaviour is identical whether `position: fixed` is set on the parent element or not. Same goes for the [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/wfpbdxqu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `flex-direction: column;` and change `justify-content:center;` to `align-items:center;` on your `.maindiv` rule, the content in the `.firstInnerDiv` will not overflow itself.

```css
.maindiv{
    position:fixed;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:center;
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background:#8c8c8c;
   }

.maindiv .firstInnerDiv{
    padding:0px 20px;
    margin-top:70px;
    border-radius:18px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    background:#fff;
 }
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">

  <div class="firstInnerDiv">
    <h2>1. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>2. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>3. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>4. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>5. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>6. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>7. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>8. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>9. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>10. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>11. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>12. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>13. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>14. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>15. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>16. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>17. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>18. this is awesome</h2>
    <h2>19. this is awesome</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi LGson, scroll bar must not be in "firstInnerDiv". which seems awful. scrollbar must be in body, which is common .